# Java webstart Security

Tags: java, jsp, java-web-start

What is the option in Java Webstart command line to skip the security check?  This is for testing purposes only.

```
javaws myfile.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two undocumented command line options in the Sun JDK: `-secure` (ironically) and `-installer`.

Be careful!

Strange way to test.

Comment: I was really interested about this parameter but it doesn't seam to work with Java 6. Can you provide additional information?

Answer (score 0):

> If the user answers "Always", the
>   certificate will be stored in the
>   certificate store pointed to by the
>   deployment.user.security.trusted.certs
>   property.

Is [this](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/security.html) what you're looking for? You can set to "Always" and store and use a self-signed key for testing.